# NPM Install Error Deploying on Vercel using NextJS

Tags: deployment, next.js, vercel

As of a few hours ago, I started getting strange errors on [Vercel](https://vercel.com/verboort) when trying to deploy my application, I am using NextJS. I have no idea what the error is, nor do I have any idea as to how this error started. I've even reverted back to code that was originally working with no luck. I will attach the error log along with my package.json.

[image]

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@africasokoni/react-flip-countdown": "^1.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^28.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^3.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.1.1",
    "@slack/web-api": "^6.0.0",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.4.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.14.0",
    "antd": "^4.16.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.13.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "browser-image-compression": "^1.0.15",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "compress-images": "^1.9.9",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0",
    "exceljs": "^4.2.1",
    "expo-server-sdk": "^3.6.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fast-geoip": "^1.1.13",
    "firebase": "^9.0.0-beta.7",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "gifsicle": "^5.2.0",
    "gsap": "^3.7.0",
    "image-size": "^1.0.0",
    "jimp": "^0.16.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.22.0",
    "mdbreact": "^4.14.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.9",
    "mozjpeg": "^7.1.1",
    "next": "^11.0.2",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^6.0.2",
    "nookies": "^2.5.2",
    "order-id": "^2.1.0",
    "photoeditorsdk": "^5.11.5",
    "pngquant-bin": "^6.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.2.15",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "pro-gallery": "^3.1.29",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-devtools": "^4.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-drag-sortable": "^1.0.6",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.2.4",
    "react-fast-compare": "^3.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.2.6",
    "react-lazyload": "^3.2.0",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-nestable": "^2.0.0",
    "react-parallax": "^3.3.0",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.14.0",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-polls": "^1.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-social-icons": "^5.5.1",
    "react-social-login-buttons": "^3.1.0",
    "react-swipeable": "^6.0.1",
    "react-tag-autocomplete": "^6.2.0",
    "read-excel-file": "^5.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "request-image-size": "^2.2.0",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.13",
    "slack": "^11.0.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.1.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.1.2",
    "stripe": "^8.148.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "styled-jsx": "^3.4.4",
    "tawkto-react": "^2.0.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "styled-jsx-plugin-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  }
```

}
`"

Comment: some missing dependencies i guess. Try luck with npm i before deployment

Comment: It builds completely fine on my computer but as soon as I try to deploy on Vercel it fails

Comment: because your local module_files may have some left over dependencies, try to delete the whole file and `npm i` again

Comment: I've already done this a few times with no luck